# depreciated `load_template` equivalent in Rails 3.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, thor

I'm attempting to increase my productivity and "store" my admittedly weak but growing understanding of rails best practices with rails [templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html).  My problem is that my [`rails-templates/base.rb`](https://github.com/BenU/rails-templates/blob/master/base.rb) has grown to an embarrassingly awkward 308 lines of code.  Even someone at my level knows that's suboptimal.  I'm eager to break that monster up into manageable pieces.

[Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/) introduces templates in ["RailsCasts #148, App Templates in Rails 2.3"](http://railscasts.com/episodes/148-app-templates-in-rails-2-3?view=asciicast).  There Bates creates an [authentication template](https://github.com/railscasts/148-app-templates-in-rails-2-3/blob/master/auth_template.rb) which loads his `base-template.rb` file using

```
load_template "/Users/rbates/code/base_template.rb"
```

I'd love to use `load_template` to do the same but it's apparently [depreciated](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/TemplateRunner/load_template).  Anything I can use instead?  Any more general advice on shaping up my template would also be gratefully received.

Comment: [Diego Carrion](http://www.diegocarrion.com/) in his [rails3-template](https://github.com/dcrec1/rails3_template/blob/master/main.rb) uses [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to do essentially the same thing.  I'm using mac, though, and would love to use something generalizable...  I'm getting the idea that this problem is unique to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current (rails 3.2), non-depreciated equivalent of `load_template` to use in rails templates is [`apply`](http://rdoc.info/github/wycats/thor/Thor/Actions%3aapply).